# How to change HEX value to EBCDIC char

Tags: java, hex, converters, ebcdic

What is the simplest way to convert HEX value to ebcdic char type in Java

e.g. The example below will return at sign but I would like to get ebcidic equivalent i.e. space char..

String hex = "40";
char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368603/convert-string-from-ascii-to-ebcdic-in-java

Comment: You are aware there are MANY edbdic code pages, all different?

Answer (score 1):

Simples and most efficient solution would probably be to write up a lookup-table yourself, based on for instance http://www.natural-innovations.com/computing/asciiebcdic.html.

Other solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368603/convert-string-from-ascii-to-ebcdic-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

To convert hex char to ebcdic (example: `C1`)

```
byte b[] = {(byte) Integer.parseInt("C1", 16)};
System.out.print(new String(b, "Cp037"));
```

The result will be `A`

Comment: This converted `0x60` to `-` and `0x6D` to `_`, though the reverse is true at some sites.