# How to convert ASCII data to EBCDIC in C#?

Tags: c#, ebcdic

I read about conversion of ASCII to EBCDIC using this link;
[Convert String from ASCII to EBCDIC in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368603/convert-string-from-ascii-to-ebcdic-in-java)

But this is in java. My requirement is in C#.Net.

So can you please help me with this?

Thanks & Regards,
Krishna Kumar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's an implementation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/ebcdic/) (by @Jon Skeet) you might find useful.

Comment: Thank you very much... I'm going through the link. 'll let you know if it help me..

Comment: The link is broken, returns 404.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above code, and found it did not work for me.

For example, '04' (0x3034) ascii translated to 0x00f000f4 ebcdic.  Problem seemed to be the encoding.

Played with several approches to change this, but finally found the best solution was the most basic.  Instead of using Convert.ToChar, I plugged the hex value into the array.

Please see following:

```
static byte[] ASCIItoEBCDIC(string asciiString)
{
    byte[] asciiToEbcdicTable = new byte[256] {
        0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x37,0x2D,0x2E,0x2F,0x16,0x05,0x25,0x0B,0x0C,0x0D,0x0E,0x0F,
        0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x3C,0x3D,0x32,0x26,0x18,0x19,0x3F,0x27,0x1C,0x1D,0x1E,0x1F,
        0x40,0x5A,0x7F,0x7B,0x5B,0x6C,0x50,0x7D,0x4D,0x5D,0x5C,0x4E,0x6B,0x60,0x4B,0x61,
        0xF0,0xF1,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF6,0xF7,0xF8,0xF9,0x7A,0x5E,0x4C,0x7E,0x6E,0x6F,
        0x7C,0xC1,0xC2,0xC3,0xC4,0xC5,0xC6,0xC7,0xC8,0xC9,0xD1,0xD2,0xD3,0xD4,0xD5,0xD6,
        0xD7,0xD8,0xD9,0xE2,0xE3,0xE4,0xE5,0xE6,0xE7,0xE8,0xE9,0xBA,0xE0,0xBB,0xB0,0x6D,
        0x79,0x81,0x82,0x83,0x84,0x85,0x86,0x87,0x88,0x89,0x91,0x92,0x93,0x94,0x95,0x96,
        0x97,0x98,0x99,0xA2,0xA3,0xA4,0xA5,0xA6,0xA7,0xA8,0xA9,0xC0,0x4F,0xD0,0xA1,0x07,
        0x20,0x21,0x22,0x23,0x24,0x15,0x06,0x17,0x28,0x29,0x2A,0x2B,0x2C,0x09,0x0A,0x1B,
        0x30,0x31,0x1A,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x08,0x38,0x39,0x3A,0x3B,0x04,0x14,0x3E,0xFF,
        0x41,0xAA,0x4A,0xB1,0x9F,0xB2,0x6A,0xB5,0xBD,0xB4,0x9A,0x8A,0x5F,0xCA,0xAF,0xBC,
        0x90,0x8F,0xEA,0xFA,0xBE,0xA0,0xB6,0xB3,0x9D,0xDA,0x9B,0x8B,0xB7,0xB8,0xB9,0xAB,
        0x64,0x65,0x62,0x66,0x63,0x67,0x9E,0x68,0x74,0x71,0x72,0x73,0x78,0x75,0x76,0x77,
        0xAC,0x69,0xED,0xEE,0xEB,0xEF,0xEC,0xBF,0x80,0xFD,0xFE,0xFB,0xFC,0xAD,0xAE,0x59,
        0x44,0x45,0x42,0x46,0x43,0x47,0x9C,0x48,0x54,0x51,0x52,0x53,0x58,0x55,0x56,0x57,
        0x8C,0x49,0xCD,0xCE,0xCB,0xCF,0xCC,0xE1,0x70,0xDD,0xDE,0xDB,0xDC,0x8D,0x8E,0xDF};

    byte[] ebcdicBinary = new byte[asciiString.Length];
    for (int pos = 0; pos < asciiString.Length; ++pos)
    {
        int ebcdicIndex = asciiString[pos];
        ebcdicBinary[pos] = asciiToEbcdicTable[ebcdicIndex];
    }
    return ebcdicBinary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below code

```
public string ConvertASCIItoEBCDIC(string strASCIIString)
{
int[] a2e = new int[256]{
0, 1, 2, 3, 55, 45, 46, 47, 22, 5, 37, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
16, 17, 18, 19, 60, 61, 50, 38, 24, 25, 63, 39, 28, 29, 30, 31,
64, 79,127,123, 91,108, 80,125, 77, 93, 92, 78,107, 96, 75, 97,
240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,122, 94, 76,126,110,111,
124,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,209,210,211,212,213,214,
215,216,217,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233, 74,224, 90, 95,109,
121,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,145,146,147,148,149,150,
151,152,153,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,192,106,208,161, 7,
32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 21, 6, 23, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 9, 10, 27,
48, 49, 26, 51, 52, 53, 54, 8, 56, 57, 58, 59, 4, 20, 62,225,
65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87,
88, 89, 98, 99,100,101,102,103,104,105,112,113,114,115,116,117,
118,119,120,128,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,154,155,156,157,158,
159,160,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,
184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,202,203,204,205,206,207,218,219,
220,221,222,223,234,235,236,237,238,239,250,251,252,253,254,255
};

char chrItem = Convert.ToChar("0");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < strASCIIString.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
       chrItem = Convert.ToChar(strASCIIString.Substring(i, 1));
       sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(a2e[(int)chrItem]));
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
       return string.Empty;
     }
}
string result = sb.ToString();
sb = null;
return result;
}
```

and check the saple code on these links

http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2007/12/convert-ascii-to-ebcdic.html

http://forums.asp.net/t/167516.aspx

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/ebcdic/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c2b074fd-4293-4bf4-b7fa-1803fc625d43

Comment: First link is broken. Second link does not cover ASCII to EBCDIC. Third link is broken. Fourth link refers to third link.