# Read/write character bytes from MQSeries

Tags: java, character-encoding

I need to read/write a string of characters using the **IBM-1047** character encoding. But when I try this in `java` using `String.getBytes("IBM-1047")` a `UnsupportedCharacterEncodingException` is thrown.

The character encoding is installed on my Windows XP system (confirmed in `Control Panel > Regional And Language Options > Advanced Tab`).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Convert String from ASCII to EBCDIC in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368603/convert-string-from-ascii-to-ebcdic-in-java), it will almost give you a full answer.

The character encoding you want to use is `Cp1047`. You can see a full list of supported character encodings [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the encoding you are using to the compiler using the `-encoding` option. See [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.ca/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html) link for details.