# Java code page table

Tags: java, ascii, codepages, ebcdic

We transfer data from mainframe to Linux/Windows servers, using a file-transfer software. To decrease the time in transfer process, we are using the `ZipDataset` class, from **JZOS API ToolKit**. There is an option to convert the data before, from **EBCDIC** to **ASCii**, and we can use all the options available in the Java environment:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

The Java default is:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_TARGET_ENCODING = "ISO8859-1";
```

---

I need to find the documentation, where I can find the *EBCDIC* character to *ASCii* **conversion** and how it is possible to create a special table conversion.

For example, for *ISO8859-1*, the *ECBDIC* character 'A' is x'C1' and the related character in *ASCii* is x'41'.

Where can I find the other doc page encoding relation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368603/convert-string-from-ascii-to-ebcdic-in-java?rq=1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC, first google hit...